# How can I determine available RAM on Raspberry Pi Pico from a VScode C program?

Tags: visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi-pico

Is there any library function or other way for a VScode C program on a Pico to determine the RAM available to it? (other than attempting `malloc()`) I've reviewed the [API documentation in the SDK](https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/modules.html) and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

If there is not defined in SDK, you can calculate it manualy. The SRAM is 246 KB = 264 * 1024 * 8 bits(total logic memory). When you use malloc and free, use +/- a simple count and a getter function.

Comment: What about the stack?